# undefined variable HTTP_POST_FILES error

Tags: php

I am writing an upload file code but when I run, it says: undefined variable: HTTP_POST_FILES
How can I solve this?

```
$a=$HTTP_POST_FILES['ufile']['name'];
```

Comment: You should be using `$_FILES['ufile']['name']`.  `$HTTP_POST_FILES` is ancient and deprecated many many years ago.

Comment: Use [`$_FILES`](http://hk.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php). **Which tutorial** ever tells you to use `$HTTP_POST_FILES` in **PHP 5**?

Comment: this was helpful to me ... when I went to the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php), it was confusing to me if **both** FILES and HTTP_POST_FILES were deprecated, or just the later ... so I do not think this should be negative voted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you set the register_global directive to ON in your PHP configuration ?

Plus try using `$_FILES` instead of `$HTTP_POST_FILES`, as this last one in now getting old

Comment: I do not think that [`$HTTP_POST_FILES`](http://php.net/HTTP_POST_FILES) needs the [`register_globals`](http://php.net/register_globals) directive to be switched on. In fact, the related ini-setting is [`register_long_arrays`](http://php.net/register_long_arrays) - both settings are deprecated btw..

Answer (score 2):

That just means you **DID NOT** define `$HTTP_POST_FILES`

**Define it** and you should be good.

---

If you are trying to use the now deprecated `$HTTP_POST_FILES`, **don't**.
 Use [`$_FILES`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) instead.

Comment: Maybe the second part first. I'd say that is the reason why it is not defined.